# a customer with more than one possible physical adress, how to design database schema?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I m new for databases and I want to build a project to understand the topics better. 
my question is : lets imagine that we are taking order for delivery to the a customer with multiple adresses. each customer may have 1 to 3 adresses registered. What is the best way to design a database like this, Should I have 3 different fields in customers table like adrs1, adrs2, adrs3 and push the adrs into that field? moreover, I should be able to query same customer with all adress fields. I coudln't figure out the way out. 
thanks from now.

Answer (score 3):

You want what is referred to as a "One-to-Many Relationship". In a scenario like yours this means that any one customer has many addresses.

You can accomplish this with a minimum of two database tables:

```
Customers
 - id (auto incrementing)
 - name
 - etc...

Addresses
 - id (auto incrementing)
 - user_id
 - details
```

The user_id column in the addresses table is a reference to the customer. After this schema is setup, you can use joins to query the data as you see fit.

A query for that might look like: (in MySQL)

```
SELECT * FROM customers
RIGHT JOIN addresses ON addresses.user_id = customers.id
```

Note: this query selects only customers who actually have addresses stored.

Further reading: http://www.techopedia.com/definition/25122/one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 1):

To learn the principals of Database-Design, attending to **[Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_forms)** is a reliable resource.
*Database normalization* is the process of representing a database in terms of relations in standard normal forms, where [first normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) is a minimal requirement. 
The Sample illustrated in the Examples part of first normal form, is the answer of your question:
Yes you may have a separate `Address` table.(as @aowie1 mentioned) 
Notice that you may Normalize and [De-Normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) you daesign based on business needs.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it is to set up a customer and an address table.  Keep all address fields in the address table and all demographic fields for the customer in the customer table:

```
CUSTOMER TABLE
id
field1
field2
etc..

ADDRESS TABLE
id
customer_id
type //billing, shipping, etc.
street1
street2
city
etc...
```

You can then join the two tables in your queries and then select which address type you need at a given time.  You would also likely have an unique index on the customer_id and type fields in the table.